# Open radlistpicker popup programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, telerik

I want to open radlistpicker fullscreen popup when I tap into my image so it will in tap event, is it possible?

Comment: Always try to find answers before posting, see http://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Answer (score 0):

If you would search using the exact title you used to write that post, you would find this as your first link: http://www.telerik.com/forums/opening-a-listpicker-programatically.

Comment: yes i notice there is a thread asking that, but the answer is now clear... it just saying using IsExpanded  and set it as true, but not saying that do i need to create a listpicker in my ui or i just can call it and if i create listpicker in my ui it will be not clean

Comment: You only stated that you don't know how to *open* fullscreen view, not that you don't know how to create it. I assumed you know how. Do you even have the Rad controls installed?

Comment: yes i have installed and trying a possible way to not put or showing my listpicker into my ui, since i don't need that in my ui just the fullscreen popup part, trying to make visibility collapsed and the fullscreen popup also visibility collapsed

Comment: No, you cannot have a standalone popup, you must have a valid control in the UI. But you can always hide it.